# Infinite Redirect Loop after moving to subdirectory

Tags: loop, redirect, deployment

I installed WordPress locally and created a theme, which worked fine. Now, as I wanted to deploy the site to a  webserver via FTP, I got stuck by an 301 Redirect loop which makes it impossible to reach the site (except for the backend login).

I moved WordPress into a subdirectory because I don't want to override the current site. **The following steps didn't work:**

- Changing `siteurl` and `home` from the `wp_options` table (tried both www and non-www)
- Editing the `.htaccess` so the RewriteBase is correct. After this didn't work, I deleted it, still no success
- Search and replace the database for entries which might have the old url (using [this](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) script)
- Deleting the `.htaccess` from the root directory (htdocs)
- Renaming the subdirectory and changing all paths again
- Overwriting the `siteurl` and `home` via wp-config.php

None of this worked. I know that the host forces to redirect to www, but no matter which kind of url type I enter, still redirecting. Any ideas?

PS: If I upload a single index.html file to this directory, it works fine...

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, ensure you test the following in a "clean" browser:

1. Set `siteurl` & `home` to `http://www.example.com/wordpress-subdirectory`
2. Set `permalink_structure` to nothing
3. Set `active_plugins` to nothing
4. Ensure there are no `WP_SITEURL` or `WP_HOME` constants defined in your `wp-config.php`
5. Remove *all* rewrite rules to do with WordPress from your `.htaccess`

Not of all these steps are necessarily required, but I'm trying to cover all bases here.

Attempt to log in. If you hit a white screen of death, it's most likely that your active theme is calling plugin-dependent functions. Change `stylesheet` and `template` in `wp_options` to `twentyfifteen` (or any default theme, and ensure it exists in your `themes` directory).

Test the frontend. All good? Go and activate each plugin again, one by one, testing the frontend each time.

Hit the problem again? Clear browser cache and reset `active_plugins`, then install & activate [Deploy Helper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/deploy-helper/)

Head over to Tools > Deploy Helper.

In the "Fix paths and URLs" section, set `From` to `http://localhost` (or whatever you were using during development) and `To` to `http://www.example.com/wordpress-subdirectory`. Leave server paths as they are.

Run <kbd>Fix</kbd>.

Activate the troublemaking plugin again and all should be well.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was (see me answer). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I spent hours trying to figure out what caused my infinite redirect problem, looking at every post and instruction video, and you are the only one who suggested clearing the permalink_structure, which actually solved my problem.

Comment: I experienced the same symptoms after copying a website to a staging domain to complete some work, including enforcing SSL. In my case the redirect loop was caused by a misconfiguration on Cloudflare where SSL was set to Flexible instead of Full.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: it is a strange server configuration. The port mapping is a bit odd, since the port 80 is mapped to a five-digit port on the other side. That's why WordPress redirected into a loop.

To fix this kind of issue enter the HTTP port number into your WordPress settings:

`http://your-domain.com:80/directory` or `https://your-domain.com:443/directory`

Thanks TheDeadMedic for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [wpbeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/):

> Go to Settings » General, change your WordPress and Site Address. If you have your address with www prefix, then change it to non-www URL, and if you have it with non-www URL then add the www prefix.

Of course, this can be edited directly in the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` entries in the database.